# How does a Task get to know when it has completed?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

The `Task` [does not maintain a wait handle](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/25/10287435.aspx) for performance reasons, and only lazily constructs one if the code were to ask one of it.

How then does a `Task` know it has been completed?

One would argue that the implementer sets the result on the `TaskCompletionSource` in their implementation but that would explain only the modern implementations and re-writes such as `System.IO.FileStream.Begin/EndReadTask`.

I followed the `Task.IsComplete` property; almost in every instance, an internal bitwise flag field (`m_stateFlags`) is set by the `TrySetResult / TrySetException` methods to indicate the status of the task.

But that does not cover all cases.

What about a method such as this?

```
public async Task FooAsync()
{
    await Task.Run(() => { });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> How then does a Task know it has been completed?

As I describe on my blog ([overview](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/04/a-tour-of-task-part-0-overview.html), [more detail](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/a-tour-of-task-part-3-status.html)), there are two kinds of tasks: Delegate Tasks (which execute code) and Promise Tasks (which represent an event).

Delegate Tasks complete themselves when their delegate completes.

Promise Tasks are completed from an external signal, using `TaskCompletionSource<T>` (or equivalent methods that are internal to the BCL).

Comment: Since we are talking about internals: There seems to be another internal mechanism to complete tasks. Seems to be an optimization for things like delays and Unwraps.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question because I have suddenly remembered that I know the answer to it.

**When using the C# Language Support Features**

It's the state machine.

If the implementer of the asynchronous method used the C# language support such as the `async` keyword in the method declaration and the `await` keyword inside the method body to await an operation intrinsic to the task, then to the extent of the task he is implementing, the state machine signals task completion by setting the result of the task.

For e.g. if his implementation was as such:

```
// client code
public async void TopLevelMethod()
{
  await MyMethodAsync();
}

// library code -- his implementation
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
    await AnotherOperationAsync();
}
```

Then the completion of `MyMethodAsync` will be entrusted to the compiler generated state machine.

Of course, the signaling of completion of `AnotherOperationAsync` will also be taken care of by the compiler generated state machine, but that is not the point here.

Recall the states inside the `MoveNext` method indicate the task completion states and in the block inside of `MoveNext` that invokes the continuation callback, it also calls `SetResult` on the `AsyncXXXMethodBuilder`.

**When *not* using the C# Language Support Features**

If, however, the implementer of the asynchronous method did not make use of the C# language features, then it is the duty of the implementer to signal the completion of the task by setting the relevant result, exception or cancelled properties on the `TaskCompletionSource` object.

For e.g.

```
public Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
  try
  {
    AnotherOperation();
    tcs.SetResult();
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    tcs.SetException(ex);
  }

  return tcs.Task; 
}
```

If the implementer did not use TPL support or invoked another operation asynchronously using the older .NET API, then too, it is the implementer's responsibility to signal task completion by explicitly setting the status of the task through one of the `Try/SetResult/Exception` etc. methods.

For e.g.

```
public Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource...
  var autoReseEvent = ...
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(() => 
                                   { 
                                     /* Work */
                                     Thread.SpinWait(1000);
                                     tcs.SetResult(...);
                                     autoResetEvent.Set();
                                    };)...;

  return tcs.Task;
}
```

**An Ill-Advised Case**

The best way to await a task is, of course, to use the `await` keyword. If, however, when implementing an asynchronous API, the implementer does this:

```
public Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  return Task.Run(...);
}
```

That would leave the consumer of his API with a sour mouth, I suppose?

`Task.Run` should only ever be used in a *fire and forget* scenario where you do not care about the point in time when the task will be completed.

The one exception to this is if you awaited the task returned by the call to `Task.Run` using the `await` keyword, like the code snippet shown below, in which case, you would be using the language support as described in the first section.

```
public async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  await Task.Run(...);
}
```

Comment: I don't mind the downvote as much as the unwillingness to provide an explanation for the downvote. If there is something wrong with my understanding, it would only help me to know, and I am open to criticism. If it is some other reason, such as stack overflow policy or something, then too, it will help me know that my thought-process as far as the question goes, is not wrong. You're not being helpful by not providing a reason along with the downvote.

Comment: (Note: I'm not the downvoter.)  There are more reasons not to use `Task.Run()`, generally speaking.  The main one being that the caller isn't expecting work to be offloaded, especially synchronous work, i.e. the caller is expecting true asynchronous all the way.  And the `async`/`await` in the last example is plain overhead, except if `Task.Run` throws an exception immediately.

Comment: @acelent I didn't understand some of the phrases you used. For e.g. a lot of times, people will refer to blocking I/O bound calls as *asynchronous* or even *threadless* tasks, and yet at other times, some articles will refer to the same work by the term *synchronous* work. When you say, *"the caller isn't expecting work to be offloaded, especially synchronous work"*, did you mean that if the work performed is a blocking I/O bound operation, the offloading to a thread pool thread is not going to do any good? If that's what you meant, I agree. Contd...

Comment: @acelent And in my examples, I did not specify the nature of work being performed by each task. For the last two snippets, I assumed that the work will be either CPU-bound work.

Comment: @acelent And I agree with your remark about there being no need to use `async` and `await` in the last snippet as that could possibly incur new heap allocations and also the switching of synchronization context, if the caller had one, and if the work I offloaded to the thread pool was CPU-bound.

Comment: @acelent At any rate, I am curious as to what you said. Could you please elaborate your comments a bit more?

Comment: I don't have much to add, but I'll clarify.  With *synchronous work*, I meant any form of CPU-intensive processing, blocking I/O and blocking waiting.  Can you provide links to those articles?  If you need to perform CPU-intensive work in the background in a graphical application, then `Task.Run()` is probably necessary and OK when used at the top-most level you can.  The same applies if your libraries perform blocking I/O or blocking waiting with no asynchronous alternative.  But that's it, e.g. libraries shouldn't use `Task.Run()`, or if they must, they should clearly document it.